# Smooth disappearance of iOS 11 search bar

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, searchbar

I am running into a small problem, I implemented the new iOS 11's style search bar in my app, and I noticed that it disappeared with a slightly different animation from the one in Messages for example. It's faster and less smooth.

Anyone has ever stumble upon this "problem" ?

Here is the code I use :

```
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
} else {
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = .white
    searchController.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    searchController.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1
}
definesPresentationContext = true
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "all_search".localized
```

**EDIT:**
[image]

I don't know if it will help you, but I am scrolling at a normal pace . 
Thanks

Comment: can you attach GIF for the same

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @Rikh not yet. What about you ?

Comment: @NicolasCharvoz nope same, stuck with the same issue. Searched around and played with trying to set the `navigationBar` to translucent and also set the `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` property but nothing seems to work.

Comment: @NicolasCharvoz try changing constraints of your `UITableView` from instead of the safe area to the superview inside of the storyboard. That works for me.

Answer (score 4):

Adding

```
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

to my viewDidLoad solved the issue, your navigation bar must not be translucent and note that extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true is being attributed to my main view which holds the tableview.

Comment: When customizing a navigation bar so its background is opaque, the layout of the view controller is inset so the top of the view ends at the bottom of the navigation bar. (It's not visible under the bar, so it's clipped) Extending the layout extends the travel of the scroll view, which extends the duration of the animation.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when your table view doesn't go all the way to the top of the view. Make sure your table view is "behind" the navigation bar and uses extended edges and extend under opaque edges if your navigation bar is opaque.

Comment: I am having this issue, but since my navbar is not translucent I cannot have my tableview under the nav bar.  any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it fixes it for me. I used a different UIViewController as the searchResultsUpdater and just set extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars as true.

```
searchResultsUpdater.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsUpdater
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { 
//your codes to implement
}, completion: nil)
```

change withDuration: in seconds

Comment: The problem is that I don't handle the animation, it's a native animation in iOS 11, so I don't have anything to code about it .